# primefaces: how to drag and swap position

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Currently I am referring to the demo of dashboard of primefaces.org.

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/dashboard.xhtml

The example given was good but I wanted my items to be able to swap position to each other on axis x and horizontal way only.

For example i have my initial position Panel A, B and C on row, i want to swap Panel A with B so that my final position would be Panel B, A, C

Is it possible to make it?

I have tried to search around for the similar examples on web.
But i have found no.

I am new for primefaces and still learning. Please advice. Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid for you need to lool into the dashboard javascript code in the source and see how to change the current behaviour to what you want to achieve, sorry...